# Filtrar resultados com relacionamento ManyToMany no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho 2 tabelas onde existe um relacionamento, `client` e `content` usando uma tabela pivot `contents_clients`, ao selecionar os `contents` do cliente "X" eu consigo saber quais conteudos pertencem ao mesmo, porém não consigo aplicar um filtro referenciando uma coluna da tabela `content`

```
$client = Client::find($client_id)->contents;
// Retorna um array de collection com os conteudos

all: [
   App\Content {#795
     id: "76",
     title: "Teste Client 1",
     content: "TESTE",
     client_alteration: null,
     target: "2",
     scheduled_to: "2016-08-30 00:00:00",
     status: "2",
     created_at: "2016-08-29 14:27:34",
     updated_at: "2016-08-29 14:27:34",
     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#794
       client_id: "1",
       content_id: "76",
     },
   },............
```

Como faço para aplicar um filtro e selecionar o `status = 2` ?
Já tentei: `$client = Client::find($client_id)->contents->where('status', 2)->get();` e recebo;

`PHP warning:  Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Comment: Para isso funcionar `contents->where` acredito que o contents tenha que ser chamado como metodo `Client::find($client_id)->contents()->where('status', 2)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando dessa forma você está disparando o [método where da collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where), e não do [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#introduction). Você poderia tentar encadeiar o método where logo após receber uma relação, mas isso resultaria em uma coleção de `contents` e não de `clients`, dessa forma:

`$contents = Client::find($id)->contents()->where('contents.status', 2)->get(`);

Para estas situações, você pode alterar a query de um eager loading, dessa forma:

```
$clients = Client::with(
    [
        'contents' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('contents.status', 2);
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

*Nota: versão do Laravel 5.3.*